Creating Point of Sale order From backend on odoo17
I created a pos.order programmatically and provided all the required fields. However, there is a field called pos_reference, which takes a string format, for example, Order 00002-003-0000.
As this field is not mandatory, I didn't provide it when creating the pos.order. If I create a pos.order without mentioning this field, it will result in this error if I try to open the UI of POS:
 error occurred while loading the Point of Sale: 
 expected string or bytes-like object


Any idea which method is responsible or creating values the pos_reference or how that value get created... So that i can do the same in my code to create a successful order from backend....
Any help will be much appreciated.
here is my code for creation of pos order:
    def order_create(self):
        config_id = self.env['pos.config'].search([('name', '=', self.aggregator_id.name)])
        if not config_id:
            config_id = self.env['pos.config'].create({
                'name': self.aggregator_id.name,
                'module_pos_restaurant': True,
            })
            config_id.setup_defaults(self.env.company)
        session_id = config_id.current_session_id
        if not session_id:
            config_id.open_ui()
            session_id = config_id.current_session_id
        pos_order_id = self.env['pos.order'].create({
            'session_id': session_id.id,
            'config_id': config_id.id,
            'company_id': self.env.company.id,
            'aggregator_id': self.aggregator_id.id,
            'lines': [(0, 0, {
                'product_id': line.product_id.id,
                'price_unit': line.price,
                'qty': line.qty,
                'tax_ids': [(6, 0, line.tax_id.ids)],
                'price_subtotal': line.untaxed_amount,
                'price_subtotal_incl': line.taxed_amount,
            })for line in self.order_lines],
            'amount_tax': self.amount_tax,
            'amount_total': self.amount_total_inc,
            'amount_paid': 0.0,
            'amount_return': 0.0,
            'is_total_cost_computed': False,
        })


